# Executing 'su' with os.exec returns error

Tags: bash, shell, go

As I understand it Go's exec function executes the command directly with the kernel, rather than creating a local a terminal session or something like that. Unfortunately, I need to use the `su` command in order to run a script, which involves running `su` then piping the root password in via stdin.

Yes I have to use `su` (business use case on devices with `sudo` disabled), and I also do need to be able to pipe the password in.

So far the code I have is as follows

```
rootRun := exec.Command("su", "-c", "whoami")

rootRun.Stderr = os.Stdout
rootRun.Stdout = os.Stdout

err = rootRun.Run()
check(err)
```

and the error is

```
su: must be run from a terminal
panic: exit status 1
```

The only way I can think to do this would be to somehow emulate a terminal on the machine with go (I dont know what packages could be used, please let me know if you know of one) or create some kind of local ssh connection that gives me a pty session to work with, but thats not great as the devices will sometimes have ssh disabled. Hopefully there is another way around this, please let me know.

Comment: `su` is trying to prevent this kind of usage with good reason. Can you a) run your Go application with root privileges, or b) make the script usable by the account your Go app is running as?

Comment: @Adrian The application has to be the thing doing privilege escalation as the person running this binary will not have knowledge of the root password, and no it must be run in a standardized environment (ships with hardware and cannot be assumed that it is changed on the other side).

Comment: So in addition to trying to circumvent `su`'s built-in security measures, you're also going to be including the root password in your application's source and binary?

Comment: @Adrian Thats the gist of it. The password/binary/src is not distributed outside the org, this is only for log collection and testing. But the environment must be consistent with that which would be seen outside

Comment: Instead of trying to force `su` to do something it should never do, it would be a little less insecure to invoke a special-purpose setuid binary to run the script. In this way you at least avoid writing the root password in the program; and it will work even if the root password is changed. (You do tell your users to change the root password immediately after unpacking the device, don't you?)

Comment: You mean it's not *intentionally* distributed outside the org. This sounds like a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: Listen, I understand these are not best practices, I am not trying to pretend that it is, and I'm not in charge of what the organization or user does. I'm just trying to execute an existing script as root so that I can ask our tech to collect certain logs that require root privileges without them needing the root password or us needing to remote in and do it manually. Is there a way, given that I am going to keep the root password in this binary encoded or not, to execute a script as root with go.

Comment: So an *internal* program that keeps the root password is OK but an *internal* configuration that enables sudo is not OK and an *internal* suid execitable is also not OK? You are working in an *interesting* company, security-wise.

Comment: Modification of a static environment is what we're trying to avoid. This has to emulate the environment found in a device that ships with a certain config

Comment: Look, the way of giving that one special executable root permissions was invented back in 1987 by Dennis Ritchie. It is called setuid. Having a setuid program on your system "modifies the environment" no more and no less than having a program that gets root permissions in some other way. The setuid way is secure though.

Comment: Should I setuid on 8 different custom binaries (which I have no control over making) that I only want run with the specific flags that wont harm the kernel?

Comment: If you believe it's safe to run these 8 executables with specific flags, you may make just one setuid program that is able to run either of those 8 executables, selectable with a command like switch, and pass the selected one its respective safe flags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running it so that it's connected to a [pseudo TTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal).

[`github.com/kr/pty`](https://godoc.org/github.com/kr/pty) and
[other packages](https://godoc.org/?q=pty) may help with this.

---

I must recap what others have written in their respective comments
that this practice is *utterly and irreversively broken.*

Comment: I do understand that this is not recommended (to say the least) but thank you for giving a solution rather than trying to change the environment in which this has to work. I will try pty now

Comment: Ended up doing full on SSH into its-self as this gives the option for me to remotely control it myself too. Thanks for the suggestion!